# Remove part of a string based on another string

Tags: java, mysql, sql

I've been looking for a while now (and have tried many solutions) but have not resolved this problem:
I need to remove text from a string based on another string.

Basically I have a customer that sends me "dirty" data and there is no possibility to modify the source.

Example address i receive (these are 2 separate fields in MySql: housnumber, appartment):

3, appartment 3F

The correct address should be:

3, Appartment F

So i need to delete the 3 from the appartment field, 3F should become F (remove housenumber from appartment where appartment starts with housnumber or something of the sort)

I have this data in MySql but would prefer to adjust it with Java as i already have an app I use to categorize appartments, buildings etc., whichever works best.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: is the data `3, appartment 3F` one column or in more then one column? Perhaps you can add a view of your table structure and some of the data.

Comment: As stated above these are 2 separate columns, housenumber and appartment :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In MySQL, you could simply use [string function `REPLACE()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_replace):

```
REPLACE(appartment, housenumber, '')
```

In a `SELECT` query:

```
SELECT housenumber, REPLACE(appartment, housenumber, '') appartment FROM mytable;
```

Or you can update your table directly:

```
UPDATE mytable SET appartment = REPLACE(appartment, housenumber, '');
```

Comment: @AdamH: sorry I am not a Java guy, but I can only imagine that such string replacement function does exist in Java.

Answer (score 0):

Ok this is what I used for JAVA and it seems to work ok, in case it can be of use to anyone else (or maybe if someone can impove it?):

```
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
  private void Remove_HouseNumber_From_Appartment() {
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------

      //Removes the house number from the appartment field
      if (Appartment.substring(0).startsWith(HouseNumber)) {
            Appartment = Appartment.replace(HouseNumber, "");

          }

    }
```